# Prove $2^{-1/x} \geq 1-\ln( 2)/x$ for $x >0$

Tags: inequality

Based on plotting both sides, this inequality seems to hold. I do not see how to prove this, however. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I recommend writing the question not only in the title...

Comment: $e^{-t} \geq 1-t$ Put $t=\frac {ln 2 } x$.

Comment: That solves it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let us study the function
$$f(x)=2^{-\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{\ln(2)}{x}-1$$

For $x>0$, the derivative is
$$f’(x)=\left(\ln(2)2^{-\frac{1}{x}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-\frac{\ln(2)}{x^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow f’(x)= \frac{\ln(2)}{x^2}\left(\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{x}}}-1\right)$$
Now since $2^{\frac{1}{x}}>1$, we can deduce that $f’(x)$ is negative for any $x>0$. Which means that $f(x)$ is decreasing.
Let us see how low $f(x)$ can get.
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=2^{-\frac{1}{+\infty}}+\frac{\ln(2)}{+\infty}-1=0$$

Which means that, for $x>0$,
$$f(x)>0$$
$$\Rightarrow 2^{-\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{\ln(2)}{x}-1>0$$
$$\Rightarrow 2^{-\frac{1}{x}}>1-\frac{\ln(2)}{x}$$